# How to get started with the mono profiler 2.8?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono

I download profile Mono 2.8 from http://hurlman.com/greghurlman_com/attachments/monoprofile2_8.zip

Add in C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Mono

Create new Project Winforms (framework 4.0) in Visual Studio 2010.

In project change "Target framework" to Mono 2.8 Profiler.

end press "Startin debuging".

**In this case an error occurs**
[image]

**How to do that would work?**

Comment: a handful of other people get this error on his blog.  http://greghurlman.com/2010/10/23/visual-studio-2010-client-profile-for-mono-2-8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [Greg Hurlman's Blog](http://greghurlman.com/2010/10/23/visual-studio-2010-client-profile-for-mono-2-8/).

"Markus" posted :

> I had the same problem, the error
>   dialog telling me I should download
>   “.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Mono”
>   in order to run my application.
>
> The trick was to create registry key.
>   For me, running Windows 7 x64, it was:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Mono
```

> I suppose for x86 it’s

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Mono
```

> (Where v4.0.30319 would be the version
>   of the current 4.0 framework
>   installed.)
>
> Hope that helps!